# CSS - Box Shadow not showing(Using react)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So im currently using react/css

This is the summary component

```
 return (
    <main>
      <article className="summary">
        <div className="summary__results">
          <h1 className="summary__title">Your Result</h1>
          <p className="summary__score">
            <p className="summary__finalscore">76</p> of 100
          </p>
          <p className="summary__descr">
            <span>Great</span> You scored higher than 65% of the people who have
            taken these tests.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="summary__details">
          <p className="summary__subtitle">Summary</p>
          <div className="summary__grades">
            {data.map((item, index) => (
              <div
                className="summary__grade"
                key={index}
                style={{ backgroundColor: bgcolors[index] }}
              >
                <p style={{ color: headingColors[index] }}>
                  <img src={item.icon} alt="itemicon" />
                  {item.category}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <span>{item.score}</span> / 100
                </p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>

          <button className="button">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
  );
```

and this is the CSS

```
/* Font import */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hanken+Grotesk:wght@500;700;800&display=swap");

:root {
  /* Colors */
  --clr-primary-lightRed-300: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);
  --clr-primary-lightRed-100: hsla(0, 100%, 67%, 0.1);

  --clr-primary-orangeyYellow-600: hsl(39, 100%, 56%);
  --clr-primary-orangeyYellow-300: hsla(39, 100%, 56%, 0.1);

  --clr-primary-greenTeal-400: hsl(166, 100%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-greenTeal-200: hsla(166, 100%, 37%, 0.1);

  --clr-primary-cobaltBlue-500: hsl(234, 85%, 45%);
  --clr-primary-cobaltBlue-200: hsla(234, 85%, 45%, 0.1);

  --clr-white-100: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --clr-paleBlue-100: hsl(221, 100%, 96%);
  --clr-lavender-200: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
  --clr-lavender-500: hsl(241, 100%, 79%);
  --clr-grayBlue-700: hsl(224, 30%, 27%);

  /* Color Gradients */
  --clr-slateBlue-400: hsl(252, 100%, 67%);
  --clr-royalBlue-400: hsl(241, 81%, 54%);

  /* Circle Color Gradients */
  --clr-violetBlueCircle-500: hsla(256, 72%, 46%, 1);
  --clr-persianBlueCircle-500: hsla(241, 72%, 46%, 0);

  /* Font Family */
  --ff-base: "Hanken Grotesk", sans serif;

  /* Font Weight */
  --fw-regular: 500;
  --fw-bold: 700;
  --fw-extrabold: 800;
}

/*  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model. */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*  2. Remove default margin  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

/*
  Typographic tweaks!
  3. Add accessible line-height
  4. Improve text rendering
*/
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/*  5. Improve media defaults */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*  6. Remove built-in form typography styles */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/*  7. Avoid text overflows */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/*  8. Create a root stacking context */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

/* General Styling */
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-base);
  font-weight: var(--fw-regular);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: var(--clr-lavender-200);

  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: grid;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    place-content: center;
  }
}

/* Button Styling */
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 0.55rem 0rem;
  background-color: var(--clr-grayBlue-700);
  color: var(--clr-white-100);
  margin: var(--content-spacing);
}

.button:is(:hover, :focus) {
  background-color: var(--clr-royalBlue-400);
}

/* Summary Styling */
.summary {
  --content-padding: 1.7rem;
  --content-spacing: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.summary__results {
  padding: var(--content-padding);
  gap: var(--content-spacing);

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--clr-slateBlue-400),
    var(--clr-royalBlue-400)
  );

  border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem;
}

.summary__title {
  color: var(--clr-lavender-200);
  font-weight: var(--fw-regular);
}

.summary__score {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius: 50%;

  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--clr-violetBlueCircle-500),
    var(--clr-persianBlueCircle-500)
  );
  color: var(--clr-lavender-500);
}

.summary__finalscore {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-extrabold);
  color: var(--clr-white-100);
}

.summary__descr {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.summary__descr span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--clr-white-100);
}

.summary__details {
  padding: var(--content-padding);
  display: grid;
}

.summary__subtitle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  color: black;
}

.summary__grades {
  margin: var(--content-spacing);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}

.summary__grades div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.summary__grades span {
  color: black;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}

.summary__grades p:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}

.summary__grade {
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

/* Responsive design for larger screen > 600 px (also calling it after all styles for mobiles have been set so i dont get specificity problems*/
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .summary {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }

  .summary__results {
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }

  .summary__details {
    border: 1px solid slategray;
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }

  .summary__descr {
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

Why when I try to apply box-shadow to the summary__details it's not showing off

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
.summary__details {
    border: 1px solid slategray;
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
}
```

Side question:Also from this image, you can tell that the two borders are not colliding is there a way to fix this so the right border goes all the way to the left instead of just stopping like a box
[image]

I want this to look like this
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:
`box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);`
just add `px` after `1` .
should look like this:

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

Comment: Wow that was the problem.Also i had to remove overflow: hidden from:

`
.summary {
  --content-padding: 1.7rem;
  --content-spacing: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
}
`

Comment: @Thodoris_Diamantidis you may accept the answer as the correct answer then.

Comment: i also put a side question there if u are able to help me that would be great @Cvijan Djukanovic!

Comment: I do not really understand that part really well, but I guess you want your border to be around summary results and summary details, or what? If that is the case than put the border on the div that is around those two, in this case, it is in article, className="summary", or if you do have something after this in article, you can always wrap those two in one div with border property.

Comment: Sorry for the late response as you can see in the image  there is a gap between these two divs(results and summary) all I want  is to fill that gap  white while still having the result right-top-bottom radius @CvijanDjukanovic I updated my question with another picture so u can understand better